# Build a basic webserver

Tags: android, linux, apache, http, webserver

I'm wondering about how to make Apache. What I want is to make a program (or script) that will allow my computer to host 1 file. Very basic there is no point except education. Just when someone goes to my IP at port 8080 it will show them index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my idea of the basic structure of a server application.

```
/* pseudocode */

listen_fd = socket(host, port);

// fork or create thread to listen for connections
{
  while (1) {
    if (0 < listen(listen_fd)) {
      fd = accept(listen_fd);
      // add fd to a data structure you can manage. I recommend epoll.
    }
  }
}

// worker process or thread
{
  while (1) {
    // wait for events on an fd. then read data into a buffer
    n = read(fd, &buf, buf_size);
    // parse request however you need to... this is a lot of the art of a web server I think.
    // load and serve content
    response_len = alloc_and_fread("index.html", &response, response_max_size);
    send(fd, response, response_len);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok I know C… but Ive never done any networking before. So where would i start? I don't know what fd is or epoll

Comment: Maybe what I'm asking is how do I use ports in general… How would I send a file out of port 8080 or for telnet 23 and how would I get input from a port.

Comment: my answer was downvoted! I am offended :P @yuxuantim are you looking for a high level understanding or code details?? There are example applications to be found anywhere if you do a google search. Here is one, http://www.paulgriffiths.net/program/c/webserv.php

Comment: I would upvote, but I don't have the rep. Im looking for a place it talks about networking with C on linux. hopefully wirh code

Comment: @yuxuantim if you haven't already, definitely just try a google search for "networking with C on linux"